# Приколы с родами в русском языке

Tags: грамотная-речь, род

```
Маша или Вася вошла в дверь и закрыла её за собой.
```

Ну что, какое тут правило применять, чтобы этот крокодил стал покладистым козлом?

Comment: Классный юмор! –

Comment: Могу сказать, что есть правило про обороты: *Маша или Вася, вошедшие в дверь и закрывшие её за собой.*

Comment: Можно так: *Вошла в дверь и закрыла её за собой Маша или Вася.*

Comment: Первый глагол можно заменить на "вошед". Маша или Вася вошед в дверь закрыв её за собой.

Comment: Оно в словаре архаизмов. Даже и не знал про него.

Comment: Род глагола прошедшего времени при существительном в единственном числе определяется по роду существительного, с которым глагол связан.
https://aa.al-shell.ru/articles/u-kakih-glagolov-est-rod/
Если глагол связан с двумя лицами разного пола, принято использовать форму глагола прошедшего времени во множественном числе.

Comment: Такого, чтобы отец или мать курили, ни Павлик, ни Ростик припомнить не могли! [Александр Мишарин. Белый, белый день // «Октябрь», 2003]     
  Даже если он или она не дали никаких поводов для ревности. [Владимир Шахиджанян. 1001 вопрос про ЭТО (№№ 501-1001) (1999)]  
Не слышал я ни от одного городского мальчика или девочки, чтобы он или она сказали: «Вот вырасту и пойду в крестьянки!» И не идет она в доярки, а он ― в дояры. [Михаил Козаков. Актерская книга (1978-1995)]

Comment: Можно было бы остановиться на варианте: «Маша или Вася вошли в дверь и закрыли её за собой», но и такой вариант выглядит неказисто. И дело тут не в согласовании подлежащего и сказуемого, а в размытости (неопределенности) повествования. Сложно понять на чем акцентируется внимание читателя: на действии «вошел в дверь и закрыл ее», или на привлечении к ответственности (за совершенные действия) вполне определенных персон «кроме Маши или Васи никто не мог этого сделать (круг подозреваемых четко очерчен, поскольку ни Федя, ни Лена этих действий не могли совершить - имеют алиби)».

Comment: Если акцент делать на действии, то достаточно сказать: «Кто то  вошел в дверь и закрыл ее за собой».
Но и в случае, когда «ищем виноватого», без «кто то» обойтись не получается: «Маша или Вася, кто то (один) из них (и никто другой), вошел в дверь и закрыл её за собой».

Comment: Кто из них, он или она, сделал предложение, неизвестно, только они сочетались законным браком. [Д. В. Григорович. Не по хорошу мил, ― по милу хорош (1889)]

Comment: Неопределенности изложения вполне допустимы в случаях, когда записи делаются на скорую руку - «для себя»:
Кажется, он (или она) писал мне, и я отвечал или посылал книжку. [А. Т. Твардовский. Рабочие тетради (1970) // «Знамя», 2005]