# Согласование определения с существительным

Tags: согласование

Возможны ли следующие варианты написания и какой смысл они несут за собой?

1. **Согласование определения с существительным.** Возможно ли использование союза "и" между неоднородными определениями (размер [огромный] и материал [каменный])? Если бы определения были однородными, то согласование было бы таким же?

> ***Я видел огромный и каменный замки*** — имеется в виду, что есть огромный замок, каменный замок?

> ***Я видел огромные и каменные замки*** — имеется в виду, что есть огромные замки, каменные замки?

> ***Я видел огромный и каменный замок*** — имеется в виду, что есть огромный каменный замок?

2. **Согласование глагола с подлежащим.**

> ***Слышатся кашель и стук | Слышится кашель и стук*** — чем данные предложения различаются?

> ***Представляет интерес статья и отрывок из неё*** - нужно ли употреблять глагол во множественном числе, если роды существительных разные (жен и муж)?

В целом есть ли какие-то строгие правила по согласованию?..

Comment: Трудные случаи согласования сказуемого с подлежащим возникают при использовании союза или (а не и, как у вас). Правила и примеры для этого случая можно найти в комментариях к https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473937

Answer (score 3):

Данные варианты "несут смысл" хренового умения формулировать мысли у их автора(не у вас само собой). То есть тот, кто их сочинял допускал намеренно или по неумению логические ошибки и искусственные парадоксы при их создании.

Замок по дефолту это огромная и каменная крепость, так что повторение через И и так уже характеристик замка смысла не прибавляет, и, либо тут замки какие-то необычные, тогда есть смысл описать в чем их необычность, либо фраза содержит бессмысленное повторение очевидного. То есть все фразы с замками неграмотные.

Хотя можно заменить на дом, тогда хотя бы этой проблемы не будет:

*Я видел огромный и каменный дома*. Очевидно, что один дом огромный, а другой каменный, хотя не ясно для чего собирать в кучу дома не имеющие между собой общих признаков, но это мелочь, видимо общий признак это И: тот и другой - дома.

*Я видел огромные и каменные дома* - скорее всего дома и огромные и каменные одновременно, так как если бы это были дома разные - огромные/каменные, то стояло бы "и,и" или "как, так и".

*Я видел и огромные, и каменные дома / Я видел как огромные, так и каменные дома*.

Но тут уже на усмотрение составителя, сложными логическими конструкциями лучше не злоупотреблять.

А лучше вообще убрать И так как не ясно, зачем она тут нужна, что она соединяет, раз нечего не разделено: *я видел огромные каменные дома* - отсутствие запятой указывает на принадлежность признаков ко всем домам.

*Я видел огромный и каменный дом* - И связывает признаки данного дома, все однозначно.

*Слышатся кашель и стук | Слышится кашель и стук*.

*Слышатся* - это про звуки, которые вместе, но разные и не являются чем-то общим, имеют разные источники. А *слышится* - когда каждый отдельный звук можно объединить, что-то одно может издавать звук кашель и стук. Слышатся кашель и стук строителей - слышатся строители, слышно строителей. Слышится кашель и стук строителя - слышится строитель, слышно строителя.

*Представляет интерес статья и отрывок из неё* - просто неграмотно составленная фраза, так как отрывок является частью статьи и употребления союза И некорректно. *Эта статья может быть интересна, особенно отрывок Х из неё* - скорее всего просто придаточное, без всяких союзов. Слово *представляет*(represent), как и *интерес*(interest) - калькированные латинизмы, неумелое использование иноязычной терминологии может приводить к ненужному усложнению языковых конструкций и созданию фраз-уродов. Поэтому не нужно пытаться совместить грамматику рунглиша и русского языка. В русском все может быть намного проще - "может быть интересно(наречие, а не существительное)", а не "может вызвать у вас эмоции интереса"(представляет интерес - "кому представляет", как можно "представить интерес", что такое "интерес"?). Если задумываться о значениях калькированных терминов и шаблонных фраз, то там такой бурелом, лучше без нужды не лезть, а если выражаться терминами, то не плакать, что непонятно ничего и не пенять на согласованное несогласуемого.

Основное правило при согласовании: формулировать фразы нужно однозначно и просто(как завещал Толстой), избегая разночтений, если не стоит иной задачи.

Comment: *Я видел огромные или каменные дома* — это как? Он не знает, что он видел и даёт варианты, что может быть?

Comment: @oleedd и огромные, и каменные? Я видел дома, которые были огромными или каменными.

Comment: Да, или: *как огромные, так и каменные*. *Я видел дома, которые были огромными или каменными* — видел какие-то одни, но не знаю какие.

Comment: @oleedd заменил на И, И, так как  "как огромные, так и каменные," - тоже подчиненная конструкция. Да, видел или огромные, но деревянные, или каменные маленькие - а не вместе)

Comment: Нет, это не подчинительный союз, он может использоваться в простом предложении.

Comment: Я встречал огромные или каменные дома, и те и другие были достаточно тяжелыми, чтобы прочно стоять на ногах.